# Circular confidence intervals about scatter points

Tags: confidence-interval, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm wondering if this is a "thing", I quite like the visual and feel it would be nice to know how much the points are likely to move from the location given by the data.

The following plot is just plotting the points

[image]

The following is the same plot, with some larger points drawn about it with a lower-alpha

[image]

Obviously these circles are pretty meaningless, as it's just some value that I've chosen for the sake of plotting here. I'm interested in knowing if there are methods to creating intervals of this nature though.

Here's the data used for the plots above:

```
    pool employee   xd1   xd2  xd1_bar  xd2_bar  x1_dev  x2_dev  color
0      1        a -5.25 -3.92    -4.25    -3.42   -1.00   -0.50    red
1      1        b -4.25 -3.92    -4.25    -3.42    0.00   -0.50    red
2      1        c -4.25 -2.92    -4.25    -3.42    0.00    0.50    red
3      1        d -3.25 -2.92    -4.25    -3.42    1.00    0.50    red
4      2        e -1.25 -0.92    -0.50    -0.17   -0.75   -0.75  green
5      2        f -1.25  1.08    -0.50    -0.17   -0.75    1.25  green
6      2        g -0.25  0.08    -0.50    -0.17    0.25    0.25  green
7      2        h  0.75 -0.92    -0.50    -0.17    1.25   -0.75  green
8      3        i  3.75  3.08     4.75     3.58   -1.00   -0.50  black
9      3        j  4.75  2.08     4.75     3.58    0.00   -1.50  black
10     3        k  4.75  4.08     4.75     3.58    0.00    0.50  black
11     3        l  5.75  5.08     4.75     3.58    1.00    1.50  black
```

Here is the code to reproduce the above (this question is not about the code, but it's included for the sake of reproducibility)

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv = """\
pool,employee,xd1,xd2,xd1_bar,xd2_bar,x1_dev,x2_dev,color
1,a,-5.25,-3.92,-4.25,-3.42,-1.0,-0.5,red
1,b,-4.25,-3.92,-4.25,-3.42,0.0,-0.5,red
1,c,-4.25,-2.92,-4.25,-3.42,0.0,0.5,red
1,d,-3.25,-2.92,-4.25,-3.42,1.0,0.5,red
2,e,-1.25,-0.92,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998,-0.75,-0.75,green
2,f,-1.25,1.08,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998,-0.75,1.25,green
2,g,-0.25,0.08,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998,0.25,0.25,green
2,h,0.75,-0.92,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998,1.25,-0.75,green
3,i,3.75,3.08,4.75,3.58,-1.0,-0.5,black
3,j,4.75,2.08,4.75,3.58,0.0,-1.5,black
3,k,4.75,4.08,4.75,3.58,0.0,0.5,black
3,l,5.75,5.08,4.75,3.58,1.0,1.5,black
"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))

data["color"] = data["pool"].replace({1: "red", 2: "green", 3: "black"})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
data.plot(
    x="xd1",
    y="xd2",
    ax=ax,
    kind="scatter",
    s=200,
    c="color",
    colorbar=False,
    fontsize=13,
)

ax.scatter(data["xd1"], data["xd2"], s=5000, alpha=0.1, zorder=-1, color="#919191")
_ = ax.axhline(0, linewidth=1, alpha=0.5, color="#919191", zorder=-1)
_ = ax.axvline(0, linewidth=1, alpha=0.5, color="#919191", zorder=-1)
_ = ax.set_title("Mean Corrected Predictor Variables", fontsize=20)
_ = ax.grid(linewidth=0.2)
_ = ax.set_xlabel("xd1", fontsize=15)
_ = ax.set_ylabel("xd2", fontsize=15)
_ = [ax.spines[x].set_linewidth(0) for x in ax.spines]
_ = ax.tick_params(which="both", length=0)
```

Comment: Could you say more precisely what the gray circles are meant to indicate?

Comment: What do you mean by the confidence interval in your problem?

Comment: Your circles have several potential interpretations.  Could they be leave-one-out prediction regions, for instance?  I think we're all struggling to understand what you might mean by "likely to move from the location given by the data."  What scenario do you have in mind that would cause the points to move and how would you be modeling this motion?